# Question related to borel measure induced by a contect...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading Paul Halmos' Measure Theory book, section 53, he defines a content on a locally compact Hausdorff space to be a set function, $\lambda$ that is additive, subadditive, monotone, and $0≤\lambda(C)<\infty$ for all $C$ compact. The "Borel sets" he considers(section 52) in this book are the smallest $\sigma$-ring generated by the class of compact sets.
I am solving the exersice of section 53 of this book but I get stuck in,

If $\mu$ is the Borel measure induced by a content $\lambda$, and if $\lambda(C)>0$ whenever $\mathring{C}\neq 0$, then $\mu(U)>0$ for every non empty $U\in \bf{U}$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{U}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{U}$ is set of open sets.